# Why additivity assumption holds in CAPM and factor models? (Screenshot of a textbook included)

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory, capm

- All the excerpts are from the book [investment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1260571157), written by Bodie. At the bottom of this post, I attached pages of the the book that show a related part of my question.

## Question

**1. Why the variance of term $E(r_{i}) = 0$?**

> We can always decompose the return on any security into the sum of its expected return plus unanticipated components:
> $$r_{i} = E(r_{i}) + e_{i} $$
> where the unexpected return, $e_{i}$ , has
> a mean of zero and a standard deviation of $\sigma_{i}$ that measures
> the uncertainty about the security return.
>
> When security returns can be well approximated by normal distributions
> that are correlated across securities, we say that they are joint
> normally distributed. This assumption alone implies that, at any time,
> security returns are driven by one or more common variables. When more
> than one variable drives normally distributed security returns, these
> returns are said to have a multivariate normal distribution. We begin
> with the simpler case where only one variable drives the joint
> normally distributed returns, resulting in a single-factor security
> market. Extension to the multivariate case is straightforward and is
> discussed in later chapters.
>
> If we suppose that there is one common factor, $m$, an unknown macroeconomic variable that affects all firms. Then we can decompose the sources of uncertainty into uncertainty about the economy as a whole, which is captured by m, and uncertainty about the firm in particular, which is captured by $e_{i}$ . In this case, we amend Equation written above to accommodate two sources of variation in return:
> $$r_{i} = E(r_{i}) + m + e_{i} $$
>
> The macroeconomic factor, $m$, measures unanticipated macro surprises. As such, it has
> a mean of zero (over time, surprises will average out to zero), with standard deviation of
> $\sigma_{m}$. In contrast, $e_{i}$ measures only the firm-specific surprise. Notice that $m$ has no subscript because the same common factor affects all securities. Most important is the fact that $m$ and $e_{i}$ are uncorrelated, that is, because $e_{i}$ is firm-specific, it is independent of shocks to the common factor that affect the entire economy. The variance of $r_{i}$ thus arises from two uncorrelated sources, systematic and firm specific. Therefore,
> $$\sigma_{i}^2 = \sigma_{m}^2 + \sigma^2(e_{i})$$

- The third equation, which is about the variance works only when the term $E(r_{i})$ is zero. However, the book does not explicitly mention that this term's variance is zero.

**2. Is the equation $r_{i} = E(r_{i}) + m + e_{i}$ the generalized form of the equation $R_{i}(t) = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{i}R_{M}(t) + e_{i}(t)$, which is mention in the excerpt below?**

> Because rates of return on market indexes such as the S&P 500 can be
> observed, we have a considerable amount of past data with which to
> estimate systematic risk. We denote the market index by $M$, with
> excess return of $R_{M} = r_{M} - r_{f}$ , and standard deviation of
> $\sigma_{M}$. Because the index model is linear, we can estimate the
> sensitivity (or beta) coefficient of a security on the index using a
> single-variable linear regression. We regress the excess return of a
> security, $R_{i}= r_{i} - r_{f}$, on the excess return of the index,
> $R_{M}$ . To estimate the regression, we collect a historical sample
> of paired observations, $R_{i}( t )$ and $R_{M}( t )$, where t denotes
> the date of each pair of observations (e.g., the excess returns on the
> stock and the index in a particular month). The regression equation is
> $$R_{i}(t) = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{i}R_{M}(t) + e_{i}(t)$$

- If the former equation is just the more generalized version than the latter, what is the difference between $r_{i}$ and $R_{i}(t)$ in each equation?

#### Below are the excerpts of the pages where I have questions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you think E(r_i) means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first question recall that
$$r_i = E[r_i] + \epsilon_i + m,$$
where $E[\epsilon_i] = E[m] = 0$ by assumption.

With this, we have:
$$E[r_i] = E[E[r_i] + \epsilon_i + m] = E[r_i]$$
as one would expect.
To find the variance:
$$Var(r_i) = E[(r_i - E[r_i])^2] = E[(\epsilon_i + m)^2] = E[\epsilon_i^2 + 2m\epsilon + m^2].$$
From this we get
$$Var(r_i) = E[\epsilon_i^2] + E[m^2] + 2E[\epsilon_im] = \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 + \sigma_m^2 + 2Cov(m, \epsilon_i),$$
where last equality follows since $E[\epsilon_i] = E[m] = 0$. If you assume $m$ and $\epsilon_i$ uncorrelated (or independent), you get the wanted result.

Regarding your second question: there you are observing the relationship between your stock-specific returns and the "market" returns. As the text-book shows, it is referring to its equation (8.5).

Comment: I have a question about the equation $E[\epsilon_{i}^2] + E[m^2] = \sigma_{\epsilon}^2 + \sigma_{m}^2 + 2Cov(m, \epsilon_{i})$.  Can you please explain more how it turns from the left hand side to right hand side of the equation?

Comment: Edited correcting the typo.